# Where do windowed functions lay in sql's order of operations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for at what point do windowed functions happen in sql. 
I know they can be used in the `SELECT` and `ORDER BY` clauses, so I am inclined to think they happen after `ORDER BY`, but before `TOP`

Comment: Have you looked at the query execution plan?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the execution order of the PARTITION BY clause compared to other SQL clauses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54357532/what-is-the-execution-order-of-the-partition-by-clause-compared-to-other-sql-cla)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window functions happen when the optimizer decides that they should happen.  This is best understood looking at the query plan.

[SQL Server advertises the *logical processing* of queries.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)  This is used to explaining scoping rules (in particular).  **It is not related to how the query is actually executed.**

Clearly, the rules for window functions are:

- The effect is *after* the `FROM`, `WHERE`, `GROUP BY`, and `HAVING` clauses are processed.
- The effect is not related to the `ORDER BY` (even if you use `order by (select null))`).
- `TOP` does not affect the processing.
- The processing occurs before `SELECT DISTINCT`.

I think the conclusion is that they are parsed in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` as with other expressions in those clauses.  There is no separate place for them.