# What is the execution order of the PARTITION BY clause compared to other SQL clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I cannot find any source mentioning execution order for `Partition By` window functions in SQL.

[image]

Is it in the same order as `Group By`?

For example table like:
[image]

[image]

```
Select *, row_number() over (Partition by Name) 
from NPtable 
Where Name = 'Peter'
```

I understand if `Where` gets executed first, it will only look at `Name = 'Peter'`, then execute window function that just aggregates this particular person instead of entire table aggregation, which is much more efficient.

But when the query is:

```
Select top 1 *, row_number() over (Partition by Name order by Date) 
from NPtable 
Where Date > '2018-01-02 00:00:00'
```

Doesn't the window function need to be executed against the entire table first then applies the `Date>` condition otherwise the result is wrong?

Comment: What are the results? And what would you expect?

Comment: How does the Window function fit in execution order?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Window functions are executed/calculated at the same stage as `SELECT`, stage 5 in your table. In other words, window functions are applied to all rows that are "visible" in the `SELECT` stage.

In your second example

```
Select top 1 *, 
row_number() over (Partition by Name order by Date) 
from NPtable 
Where Date > '2018-01-02 00:00:00'
```

`WHERE` is logically applied before `Partition by Name` of the `row_number()` function.

Note, that this is logical order of processing the query, not necessarily how the engine physically processes the data.

If query optimiser decides that it is cheaper to scan the whole table and later discard dates according to the `WHERE` filter, it can do it. But, any kind of these transformations must be performed in such a way that the final result is consistent with the order of the logical steps outlined in the table you showed.

Comment: Thank you. So it will depend on optimizer whether to execute the where condition first or not as far as the final result is consistent?

Comment: @NewPy, yes, the table that you showed with the order of the query processing steps is for the **logical** order. It defines what the final result of the query will be. It is up to the engine/optimiser to choose a physical plan of execution that would produce the required result. Optimiser considers many things and in some cases it may choose, for example, to scan the whole table instead of searching the index. It will apply the filter eventually, but filtering may happen later than you "expected". In any case, the final result of the query will be correct and correspond to the logical order.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Baranov excellent answer, so, can I rely 100% on logical processing to know which objects (columns, tables, etc) I have "available" in **subsequent query clauses (stages)**?

Comment: @jwa, if I understood you correctly, you are talking about parsing the text of the query (such as, would the parser "know" what a, say, table or column alias means in various parts of the query). It may correspond to the order of those logical execution stages shown in this question, or it may not. I think these are different things. For example, if you define an alias for a column name in the SELECT part, the SQL Server would not recognize it in the WHERE part, but other databases may parse it differently. You'd better ask a new question.

Comment: Hi @Vladimir Baranov, look, I asked this yesterday [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77481764/can-i-rely-100-on-logical-processing-to-know-which-objects-columns-aliases-ta)

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, the "scoping rules", look my question please @Vladimir Baranov

Comment: @jwa, I'm not good at explaining this stuff. Other people are giving good answers I think

Answer (score 3):

`row_number()` (and other window functions) are allowed in two clauses:

- `SELECT`
- `ORDER BY`

The function is parsed along with the rest of the clause.  After all, it is a function present in the clause.  In both cases, the `WHERE` clause would be -- logically -- applied first, so the results would be *after* filtering.

Do note that this is a *logical* parsing of the query.  The actual execution may have little to do with the structure of the query.

Answer (score 3):

It is part of the `SELECT` phase of the query execution. There are different types of SELECT clauses, based on the query.

- SELECT FOR
- SELECT GROUP BY
- SELECT ORDER BY
- SELECT OVER
- SELECT INTO
- SELECT HAVING

PARTITION BY comes in the `SELECT OVER` clause. Here, a window of the result set is generated out of the result set generated in the previous stages: FROM, WHERE, GROUP BY etc.

> The OVER clause defines a window or user-specified set of rows within
>   a query result set. A window function then computes a value for each
>   row in the window. You can use the OVER clause with functions to
>   compute aggregated values such as moving averages, cumulative
>   aggregates, running totals, or a top N per group results.
>
> `OVER ( [ PARTITION BY value_expression ] [ order_by_clause ] )`
>
> Arguments
>
> **PARTITION BY** Divides the query result set into partitions. The window
>   function is applied to each partition separately and computation
>   restarts for each partition.
>
> **value_expression** Specifies the column by which the rowset is
>   partitioned. value_expression can only refer to columns made available
>   by the FROM clause. value_expression cannot refer to expressions or
>   aliases in the select list. value_expression can be a column
>   expression, scalar subquery, scalar function, or user-defined
>   variable.
>
> Defines the logical order of the rows within each
>   partition of the result set. That is, it specifies the logical order
>   in which the window functioncalculation is performed.
>
> **order_by_expression** Specifies a column or expression on which to sort.
>   order_by_expression can only refer to columns made available by the
>   FROM clause. An integer cannot be specified to represent a column name
>   or alias.

You can read more about it [SELECT-OVER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)