# can I rely 100% on logical processing to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server

The documentation says that logical processing is used to know what *I have available for the next clauses of a query*, but later **it contradicts itself** by saying that the order can change, that confuses me.

[Here, logical processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#logical-processing-order-of-the-select-statement)

> Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement
>
> The following steps show the logical processing order, or binding
> order, for a SELECT statement. This order determines when the objects
> defined in one step are made available to the clauses in subsequent
> steps. For example, if the query processor can bind to (access) the
> tables or views defined in the FROM clause, these objects and their
> columns are made available to all subsequent steps. Conversely,
> because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived
> columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding
> clauses. However, they can be referenced by subsequent clauses such as
> the ORDER BY clause. **The actual physical execution of the statement is
> determined by the query processor and the order may vary from this
> list.**
>
> ```
> 1. FROM
> 2. ON
> 3. JOIN
> 4. WHERE
> 5. GROUP BY
> 6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
> 7. HAVING
> 8. SELECT
> 9. DISTINCT
> 10. ORDER BY
> 11. TOP
> ```
>
> Warning
>
> The preceding sequence is usually true. **However, there are uncommon
> cases where the sequence may differ.**
>
> For example, suppose you have a clustered index on a view, and the
> view excludes some table rows, and the view's SELECT column list uses
> a CONVERT that changes a data type from varchar to integer. In this
> situation, the CONVERT may execute before the WHERE clause executes.
> Uncommon indeed. Often there is a way to modify your view to avoid the
> different sequence, if it matters in your case.

1. Does this mean that, for example, there will be times when the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `FROM` clause and times when the `FROM` clause is executed first and then the `WHERE` clause?
2. Can I rely 100% on *logical processing* to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?

I also read this from a StackOverflow expert on SQL:

> SQL, by the way, is a descriptive language not a procedural language.
> **A query does not specify the "order of execution". That is determined
> by the compiler and optimizer.** What you are referring to is the "order
> of parsing", which explains how identifiers are resolved in the query.

3. So, what is the point of *logical processing* if *physical processing* (the database, optimizer, indexes, etc at the end of the day) decides the order of execution in a query?
4. Does this mean that *physical processing* can "skip" (alter, modify, I don't know what the right word is) the *logical processing* steps?
5. Does the *logical processing* is executed **first** and then the *physical processing*?, or how?

Comment: maybe you can ask this at [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I think you overthink this. sql server can do anything as long as the "final result" of the query matches your statement. It might even put stuff into a nosql database, and then rewrite your sql into another syntax, and then come back with results. But it's up to you as developer to write a proper query, ie. not jump ahead and use SELECT alises in a WHERE (which isn't allowed). Logical processing sets in stone the final result you want to see, and physical parts deliver this result in hopefully shortest possible time

Comment: "*Logical processing sets in stone the final result you want to see*" - so, why does it say that one clause may come before another on certain occasions and sometimes after? @siggemannen

Comment: because expected result != execution. Execution isn't set in stone

Comment: A stupid example. You work as painter. Someone tells you to paint a house white. But this someone doesn't care if you use a brush, a machine, or a nail polish, as long as you do it white and as quickly as possible. He also doesn't care if you start from the living room, bathroom or do a couple of hours each room

Comment: The "Warning" in the docs isn't really correct. It mixes up physical and logical execution, so it should probably be rewritten. It's also not that uncommon, `CONVERT` should really be `TRY_CONVERT` if there is any possibility of an error.

Comment: "*because expected result != execution. Execution isn't set in stone*" - So, the *logical processing* is what **we as humans have to respect, the "rules of the game"** and the *physical processing* has to replicate the result of that *logical processing* but (what we tell it) "following its own path", but always faithful to the *logical processing*? @siggemannen

Comment: I like your "stupid" example @siggemannen

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Does this mean that, for example, there will be times when the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `FROM` clause and times when the `FROM` clause is executed first and then the `WHERE` clause?

No, because in order to filter something (WHERE) you need to know what you are filtering (FROM). So some sort of FROM will certainly happen before some sort of WHERE.
I am saying "some sort" because the exact FROM that actually happens may not be the exact FROM you have specified in your query. This includes not only the order of the FROMed objects, but even their composition (the RDBMS may substitute an object with an equivalent object (table/view) or completely omit FROMing an object if it does not affect the final result).

> 2. Can I rely 100% on logical processing to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?

No, you rely on the SQL grammar for that. The available aliases depend on the nesting level at each textual point of your query.

> 3. So, what is the point of logical processing if physical processing (the database, optimizer, indexes, etc at the end of the day) decides the order of execution in a query?

The point of logical processing is to establish the correct result that needs to be achieved. Having done that, you can come up with a completely different way of actually achieving that result, that involves accessing and processing data in very unexpected ways.

> 4. Does this mean that physical processing can "skip" (alter, modify, I don't know what the right word is) the logical processing steps?

The physical processing is concerned with only producing the result that the logical processing would have produced. It does not care in the slightest about preserving any sort of the order of operations, as long as the final result is the same as the logical processing would have achieved. See [What exactly is the "as-if" rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718262/what-exactly-is-the-as-if-rule).

> 5. Does the logical processing is executed first and then the physical processing?, or how?

That is a philosophical question.
You may say that it is, because the query optimizer is written in such way that its result will match that of the logical processing, so in this sense the logical processing is "executed first" (as it influences the decisions of the optimizer from step 1).
Or you may say that the logical processing is not executed at all.

Comment: Answer Point 1 mixes up physical and logical. Point 2 says "No, you rely on the SQL grammar" but the logical processing essentially *is* the grammar ie it is the logical result of that grammar. Should note that runtime errors (eg div by zero) can transcend the logical processing (move about between scopes) and therefore regarding such errors the physical result sometimes isn't the same as the logical.

Comment: @Charlieface Point 1 was only about physical, although neither physically nor logically can you filter something before deciding what you are going to be filtering. Point 2, I don't believe the logical processing is the grammar, especially in the narrow sense of alias availability.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Does this mean that, for example, there will be times when the WHERE clause is executed before the FROM clause and times when the FROM clause is executed first and then the WHERE clause?**
If you mean at the *logical* stage: no, `FROM` always comes logically before a `WHERE`. It is certainly possible for a `WHERE` filter physically to happen first, for example startup filters which do not depend on the tables. But the result will be the same.
That (rather badly written) *Warning* in the documentation is warning about runtime errors, especially in the case of `CONVERT` (although it can also happen with divide-by-zero and others). What can happen is that the compiler does not take into account possible error conditions, and assumes the query will finish correctly, so it reorders conditions in a way that can cause an error.
The way around such errors is to use constructs which force the ordering, such as `TRY_CONVERT`, `CASE` or `NULLIF`.

**2. Can I rely 100% on logical processing to know which objects (columns aliases, tables, etc) I have "available" in subsequent query clauses?**
Yes, the SQL grammar enforces what the result of the logical processing should be.

**3. So, what is the point of logical processing if physical processing (the database, optimizer, indexes, etc at the end of the day) decides the order of execution in a query?**
They are two separate things: logical defines the *what*: what is the intended result (joins, columns, filters, rowgoals), physical defines the *how*: how does the compiler construct access methods (indexing), which join strategies, where to place filters, to create that result.

**4. Does this mean that physical processing can "skip" (alter, modify, I don't know what the right word is) the logical processing steps?**
Yes, it may. There are many ways your query can be transformed, using various optimizations and simplifications. The result should be the same.

**5. Does the logical processing is executed first and then the physical processing?, or how?**
The compiler will analyze the query according to the grammar to make a logical query plan, then analyze what access methods are available to execute it. Again, two different things.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface - So the physical processing has to **replicate the result** of the logical processing only in a different way?

Comment: "*logical defines the what, physical defines the how.*" - what exactly does that refer to? I've seen it a lot around here on StackOverflow? @Charlieface

Comment: Added more wording. The logical processing means the compiler's understanding of what you *want* eg you want the results of two joins, with a filter, a rowgoal (TOP) and some columns selected. The physical processing is the actual way the compiler gets that, eg using various indexing and joining strategies. The logical processing doesn't actually exist as such, it's just the understanding of what the query defines.

Comment: Can we say that the purpose of the logical processing is **only** to explain the *scoping rules*? @Charlieface

Comment: No it also defines the rest of the query, such as filtering, rowgoals etc. It just doesn't define *how* that should be achieved.